# Is the EHIC still valid/recommended for travel to the UK post Brexit

Tags: uk, brexit, ehic

Is the European Health Insurance Card still useful/required/recommended for travel to the UK (post Brexit) or is something else required?

Edit: I'm legally resident in France and am on the French social security system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The European Health Insurance Card is still accepted in the UK under the EU-UK Trade and Cooperation Agreement that came into force at the end of the Brexit transition period. You may want to supplement it with some form of travel insurance but reciprocal healthcare agreements is one area where the UK and EU could agree that not much should change.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UK_Global_Health_Insurance_Card) provides a lot details about all this.